# spark wholeTextFiles fails for large data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I use pyspark version 1.5.0 with Cloudera 5.5.0. All scripts are running fine except when I use `sc.wholeTextFiles`. Using this command gives an error:

`Kryo Serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available:0, required: 23205706. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max`

However, I don't find the property `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` in the spark web UI; it is not present under the `Environment` tab in Spark web UI. The only "kryo" in this page is the value `org.apache.spark.selializer.KryoSerializer` of the name `spark.serializer`.

Why can't I see this property? And how to fix the problem?

**EDIT**

Turns out that the **Kryo error** was **caused by *a printing to the shell***. Without printing, the error is actually `java.io.IOExceptionL Filesystem closed`!
The script now works correctly for a small portion of the data, but running it on all of the data (about `500GB`, `10,000 files`) returns this error.

I tried to pass in the propery `--conf "spak.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2000"`, and it seems that it allows a slightly larger part of the data to be read, but it still ultimately fails on the full data. It takes 10-15 minutes of running before the error appears.

The RDD is big, but the error is produced even when only doing `.count()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass such property when submitting a job. This is why it's not in Cloudera UI.
http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_apps.html

In your case: `--conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max = 64M"` (for example)

Also, I'm not sure but it might happen that if you increase Kryo buffer you might want to increase akka frame size.

Comment: No difference, running the following: `spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors 6 --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max = 128M" /dev/myScript.py`. Still `Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Availabale: 0, required: 23205706`.

Comment: it might be small `m` but I don't thing this is the case…
How big are files that you are trying to read? How many are there? You are creating quite a PairRDD with this function, maybe it's over few GBs?

Comment: Thank you. Somehow the huge printing to the shell, by calling take(1) of the wholeTextFiles, is what caused the kryo error. Without it the error is different, and I edited correspondingly.